# How to auto-hide menu-bar(s) in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8

I remember having hidden menu-bars (File, Edit, View ... menus just below the title bar) in Windows 7, which are activated/shown by pressing the alt key. I don't know if it was the default behavior or I changed it. Since I upgraded to Windows 8.1, menu-bars (in all  of the windows) are shown/displayed again. Can I make them hidden (to save display space) by default and displayed by the alt key?

Answer (score 1):

Most Windows programs do not have an option to toggle the menu bar. Internet Explorer has this in the right-click menu of the menu bar.

If you're talking about the *ribbon*, you can collapse it by **double-clicking any tab**. It will expand temporarily when you click any tab, and collapse again automatically.

Comment: (my) `iexplore` behaves just the way I wanted; does not display the menus till I press the alt key. I am looking for a way to make other applications behave like it...

Comment: @user3648895 "I am looking for a way to make other applications behave like it"  It's up the applications to decide how to display their menus. There's no one-stop Windows setting that controls it for all applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the Tabstrip, its not considered to be a menu.

But regardless, I did find the option to always show the menu in case it works for you (it didn't for me).

In explorer, go to the tab View, at the right click options.

In the tab view (2nd tab) one of the first options is `[ ] Always show the menu`.

Note, I am not entirely sure about what the exact text is, as my windows is dutch, so I had to translate.

Comment: I am referring to "File, Edit, View ... menus just below the title bar" in the explorer and other windows. That option was already unchecked, I checked and unchecked it again, nothing has changed...

Comment: The file, edit and view are the tabstrip.

Comment: EDIT: I mean ribbon

Comment: right click the menu bar, select ( minimize the ribbon ) ^^